# Can´t add System.Net reference to Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I`m not being able to add the System.Net reference to my Xamarin Forms Project in order to use Dns class. I want to use the Dns.Resolve(String) method but I get that Dns does not exist.

When I try to add an assembly reference using the Reference Manager, it shows "All of the Framework assemblies are already referenced" and I can´t add anything.

Any sugestions?

Comment: I assume you're using a PCL.  Each PCL profile has a defined subset of the .NET Framework available to it.  You can't just add additional framework libraries.  If there is some missing functionality you can use DI to include it from your platform projects, or can try to find a PCL compatible package that provides the same functionality.

Comment: You are right. I will try use DI to do the implementation. Thank you for your reply

Comment: DI Means..? How To Implement it..? I am also facing the same issue.. Can you have any example

Comment: DI means Dependency Injection. Here you have an example http://www.codenutz.com/using-dependency-injection-container-xamarin-forms-labs/

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit tricky, but you can manually add something like this

```
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http">
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.29\lib\portable-net40+sl4+win8+wp71+wpa81\System.Net.Http.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

to your pcl .cproj file into ItemGroup section. And do not forget to specify the correct path in the link